# jQuery scroll to bottom of div is very tempremental

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am developing an instant messaging page for my website and I consequently want the div to be scrolled to the bottom so the newest message can be seen. The page is saved as a php file and uses jQuery to do the scrolling.

**The code:**

```
$(function() {
var wtf    = $('#chat');
var height = wtf[0].scrollHeight;
wtf.scrollTop(height);
});
```

Currently I use the following code however it is very temperamental and only works about 1 in 4 times, I have not added the webpage code as it it several hundred lines however I can if necessary. Is there a better solution which works more consistently?

Comment: Hi, can you explain more about it being inconsistent? What happens when it doesn't work, what errors do you get in your dev tools? Do you fire this only on page load or is it fired at regular intervals?

Comment: This is only fired on page loads, the inconsistency is very random and there seems to be no pattern, sometimes it scrolls to the bottom, sometimes it stays at the top. What development tool should I be using to view errors? I am using brackets and standard Google Chrome. My research has shown me that this code doesn't always work so I am wondering if there is a more consistent solution.

Comment: Open Chrome's dev tools and have a look at the console. Then, inspect wtf and height with console.log(wft);console.log(height); Maybe that's going to help you with your debugging efforts :)

Comment: It always works the first time the page loads and then it takes a lot of page refreshed to get it to work a second time. I tried enter the commands mentions in the comment above and got an error stating that " Uncaught ReferenceError: wft is not defined"

Comment: Could the fact that it always works when the url is inputted into the url bar and entered, show why there is a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alex, I would try to load this function with

```
$(window).load(functiion() {
   //your code here
   var wtf    = $('#chat');
   var height = wtf[0].scrollHeight;
   wtf.scrollTop(height);
}
```

The difference between that and document.ready is document.ready fires when the document is loaded which is before the whole page loads in some instances. It will be a slightly slower load time if you do this but your script should at least work consistently. I have faced similar troubles. Give it a try and let me know how it works for you.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem and explained the reason the problem was happening as sometimes the data had fully loaded before the script had executed and sometimes it hadn't.

Answer (score 0):

Add an anchor right after the div... `<a href="#bottomofdiv"></a>` then when you refresh... `yourpage#bottomofdiv`